# add to values separated by a comma

Tags: javascript

I searched for a solution but could not find,

I have the current script, the numbers are random (changing at different amounts),

```
var totalAmount = [55.99,7.00];
```

I'm trying to add the two values separated by the comma to equal e.g."`totalAmout = 62.99;`"

Comment: Is this a string or a comma separated list of numbers like you wrote?

Comment: a comma separated list of numbers

Comment: @user1345428: So this is rather `var totalAmount = [55.99,7.00];`, not `var totalAmount = 55.99,7.00;`?

Comment: Your JavaScript is pseudo-valid. It's valid syntax, but probably not doing what you think it's doing. Comma is a special operator.

Comment: Like Tadeck seems to be saying, it sounds like you might want an array, not a comma separated list of numbers... which as Ates mentioned, may not do what you think.

Comment: I don't get it...looks pretty trivial to me. What's wrong with just totalAmount[0] + totalAmount[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed it to an array. You can add to an array in javascript with `.push()`;

```
var totalAmount = [55.99, 7.01];
totalAmount.push(5);
console.log(totalAmount); // produces something like [55.99, 7.01, 5]
```

[edit] Yeah, the whole format of the question threw me off. If you're wanting the SUM of an array of numbers, you can do so with a for loop:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < totalAmount.length; i++)
    total += parseFloat(totalAmount[i]);
}
```

`total` will have the sum of the array, and it work for any length array. If we didn't have parseFloat, it might do some weird things since the concatenate and addition operators are both `+` in JavaScript. So we do `parseFloat(totalAmount[i])` and that will make sure if even if you have a string like `"55.55"` in your array, it will be used as a number and not a string.

Comment: OP says he's trying to add the two numbers (like `totalAmount[0] + totalAmount[1]`), not add a value to the list.

Comment: thanks Mike, exactly what I want.

Comment: Well if it was that easy, I'll make it an answer heh..

Comment: This is a better answer if you're trying to sum up every element in the array..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try this:

```
var totalAmount = [55.99,7.00];
var sum = totalAmount[0] + totalAmount[1]; //Add array elements 0 and 1
```

This of course assumes your array has at least two elements.

Comment: You can make it better. [55.99, 7.00].reduce(function(p,v) { return p+v; }, 0);

Comment: sometimes it's three valyes e.g. [55.99,7.00,5.00]

Comment: @lightblade - I don't think `reduce` is in too many browsers though, right?